# How to scale this query

Tags: database, postgresql, authorization, access-control, postgresql-9.3

### Use Case

The system I'm working with has *plans*. Each plan is directly connected to multiple *account entities*. These account entities are used to decide who is authorized to view the plan.

An account entity can be one of the following types:

- Individual: A person with no office.
- Office member: A person with an office.
- Office: A group of office members.

Individuals and office members are all attached to user accounts.

Each account entity type gives a different type of authorization:

- If a plan is directly connected to an individual, that individual can view the plan.
- If a plan is directly connected to an office member, every office member in that office member's office can view the plan.
- If a plan is directly connected to an office, every office member in that office can view the plan.

### Implementation

This authorization logic is expressed in the form of a database view. The view has two columns, the account_entity_id of an individual or office_member, and the ID of a plan they have access to. This database view is then joined to other queries to establish access throughout the system.

### Schema

```
-- team_members
CREATE TABLE team_members (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    plan_id integer NOT NULL,
    care_role_id integer DEFAULT 0,
    account_entity_id integer,
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    deleted boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX idx_team_member_plan_id_care_role_id_deleted ON team_members USING btree (plan_id, care_role_id, deleted);
CREATE INDEX idx_team_members_account_entity_id ON team_members USING btree (account_entity_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_team_members_plan_account_entity ON team_members USING btree (plan_id, account_entity_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_team_members_plan_dashboard ON team_members USING btree (account_entity_id, deleted, created DESC, plan_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_team_members_plan_id ON team_members USING btree (plan_id);

-- account_entities
CREATE TABLE account_entities (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    account_id integer NOT NULL,
    entity_id integer NOT NULL,
    entity_type_id integer NOT NULL,
    rbac_role_uuid character(36) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar
);
CREATE INDEX idx_account_entities_entity_id_entity_type_id_account_id ON account_entities USING btree (entity_id, entity_type_id, account_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_account_entities_entity_type_id ON account_entities USING btree (entity_type_id);

-- office_members
CREATE TABLE office_members (
    person_account_entity_id integer NOT NULL,
    office_account_entity_id integer NOT NULL,
    rbac_role_uuid character(36) DEFAULT NULL::bpchar
);
CREATE INDEX idx_office_members_location_id ON office_members USING btree (office_account_entity_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_office_members_rbac_role_uuid_location_id ON office_members USING btree (rbac_role_uuid, office_account_entity_id);

-- plans
CREATE TABLE plans (
    person_full_name text,
    plan_id integer
);
CREATE INDEX idx_plans_plan_id ON plans (plan_id, person_first_name);
```

### Query to create view

```
-- Plan <-> individual or office member
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS public.accessible_plans;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.accessible_plans AS (

    -- Plan <-> individual
    SELECT tm.plan_id content_id, ae_i.id account_entity_id
    FROM public.team_members tm
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_i ON ae_i.id = tm.account_entity_id
      AND ae_i.entity_type_id = 2 -- Individual
    WHERE tm.deleted = FALSE

    UNION

    -- Plan <-> office <-> office member
    SELECT tm.plan_id content_id, ae_om.id account_entity_id
    FROM public.team_members tm
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_o ON ae_o.id = tm.account_entity_id
      AND ae_o.entity_type_id = 3 -- Office
    INNER JOIN public.office_members om ON om.office_account_entity_id = ae_o.id
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om ON ae_om.entity_id = om.person_account_entity_id
      AND ae_om.entity_type_id = 4 -- Office member
    WHERE tm.deleted = FALSE

    UNION

    -- Plan <-> office member <-> office <-> office member
    SELECT tm.plan_id content_id, ae_om_om.id account_entity_id
    FROM public.team_members tm
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om ON ae_om.id = tm.account_entity_id
      AND ae_om.entity_type_id = 4 -- Office member
    INNER JOIN public.office_members om ON om.person_account_entity_id = ae_om.entity_id
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_o ON ae_o.entity_id = om.office_account_entity_id
      AND ae_o.entity_type_id = 3 -- Office
    INNER JOIN public.office_members om2 ON om2.office_account_entity_id = ae_o.id
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om_om ON ae_om_om.entity_id = om2.person_account_entity_id
      AND ae_om_om.entity_type_id = 4 -- Office member
    WHERE tm.deleted = FALSE
);
```

#### EXPLAIN ANALYZE of source query from view (above)

```
Unique  (cost=488461.98..496389.21 rows=1056964 width=8) (actual time=175241.204..200905.191 rows=52171056 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=488461.98..491104.39 rows=1056964 width=8) (actual time=175241.202..190780.286 rows=61152360 loops=1)
        Sort Key: tm.plan_id, ae_i.id
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1076024kB
        ->  Append  (cost=6.92..353801.83 rows=1056964 width=8) (actual time=5828.072..30005.448 rows=61152360 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.92..1035.20 rows=43 width=8) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_account_entities_entity_type_id on account_entities ae_i  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (entity_type_id = 2)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on team_members tm  (cost=6.50..1024.09 rows=267 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_i.id)
                          Filter: (NOT deleted)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_team_members_account_entity_id  (cost=0.00..6.43 rows=267 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_i.id)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=8985.39..185496.61 rows=632976 width=8) (actual time=4637.744..4637.744 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (ctm_1.account_entity_id = ae_o.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on team_members ctm_1  (cost=0.00..111477.86 rows=5218086 width=8) (actual time=0.019..1758.942 rows=5218086 loops=1)
                          Filter: (NOT deleted)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=8801.25..8801.25 rows=14731 width=12) (actual time=294.159..294.159 rows=82510 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=5136.32..8801.25 rows=14731 width=12) (actual time=141.155..269.546 rows=82510 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (ae_om.entity_id = om.person_account_entity_id)
                                ->  Seq Scan on account_entities ae_om  (cost=0.00..3144.95 rows=99379 width=8) (actual time=0.029..28.814 rows=99019 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (entity_type_id = 4)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 21927
                                ->  Hash  (cost=4911.47..4911.47 rows=17988 width=12) (actual time=140.625..140.625 rows=82510 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=1528.62..4911.47 rows=17988 width=12) (actual time=19.159..117.250 rows=82510 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (om.office_account_entity_id = ae_o.id)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on office_members om  (cost=0.00..2334.52 rows=99252 width=8) (actual time=0.004..51.164 rows=99044 loops=1)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=1253.52..1253.52 rows=22008 width=4) (actual time=19.097..19.097 rows=21885 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 770kB
                                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_account_entities_entity_type_id on account_entities ae_o  (cost=0.42..1253.52 rows=22008 width=4) (actual time=0.008..14.818 rows=21885 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (entity_type_id = 3)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=21415.31..156700.39 rows=423945 width=8) (actual time=1190.264..19177.727 rows=61152360 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (ctm_2.account_entity_id = ae_om_1.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on team_members ctm_2  (cost=0.00..111477.86 rows=5218086 width=8) (actual time=0.034..1105.484 rows=5218086 loops=1)
                          Filter: (NOT deleted)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=21291.98..21291.98 rows=9866 width=8) (actual time=1189.954..1189.954 rows=400053 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 32 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=17054.58..21291.98 rows=9866 width=8) (actual time=801.650..1105.307 rows=400053 loops=1)
                                Hash Cond: (ae_om_1.entity_id = om_1.person_account_entity_id)
                                ->  Seq Scan on account_entities ae_om_1  (cost=0.00..3144.95 rows=99379 width=8) (actual time=0.018..22.423 rows=99019 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (entity_type_id = 4)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 21927
                                ->  Hash  (cost=16903.99..16903.99 rows=12047 width=8) (actual time=799.013..799.013 rows=400053 loops=1)
                                      Buckets: 2048  Batches: 32 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=13265.90..16903.99 rows=12047 width=8) (actual time=384.006..703.187 rows=400053 loops=1)
                                            Hash Cond: (ae_om_om.entity_id = om2.person_account_entity_id)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on account_entities ae_om_om  (cost=0.00..3144.95 rows=99379 width=8) (actual time=0.011..22.382 rows=99019 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: (entity_type_id = 4)
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 21927
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=13082.01..13082.01 rows=14711 width=8) (actual time=380.308..380.308 rows=400053 loops=1)
                                                  Buckets: 2048  Batches: 32 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=9855.99..13082.01 rows=14711 width=8) (actual time=99.375..294.180 rows=400053 loops=1)
                                                        Hash Cond: (om2.office_account_entity_id = ae_o_1.id)
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on office_members om2  (cost=0.00..2334.52 rows=99252 width=8) (actual time=0.003..12.347 rows=99044 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=9631.01..9631.01 rows=17999 width=8) (actual time=99.061..99.061 rows=99039 loops=1)
                                                              Buckets: 2048  Batches: 8 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1025kB
                                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1533.57..9631.01 rows=17999 width=8) (actual time=9.522..72.621 rows=99039 loops=1)
                                                                    Hash Cond: (om_1.office_account_entity_id = ae_o_1.entity_id)
                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on office_members om_1  (cost=0.00..2334.52 rows=99252 width=8) (actual time=0.002..11.773 rows=99044 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=1258.47..1258.47 rows=22008 width=8) (actual time=9.497..9.497 rows=21885 loops=1)
                                                                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 855kB
                                                                          ->  Index Scan using idx_account_entities_entity_type_id on account_entities ae_o_1  (cost=0.42..1258.47 rows=22008 width=8) (actual time=0.016..5.457 rows=21885 loops=1)
                                                                                Index Cond: (entity_type_id = 3)
Total runtime: 203539.978 ms
```

### Typical query that uses view

```
SELECT plan.plan_id, plan.person_full_name
FROM public.plans AS plan
INNER JOIN public.accessible_plans acp ON acp.content_id = plan.plan_id
    AND acp.account_entity_id = 30710 -- Logged in office member
ORDER BY person_full_name ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 15
```

#### EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
Limit  (cost=4972.60..4972.64 rows=15 width=21) (actual time=846.592..846.595 rows=15 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=4972.60..4973.32 rows=285 width=21) (actual time=846.591..846.592 rows=15 loops=1)
        Sort Key: plan.person_full_name
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2735.50..4965.61 rows=285 width=21) (actual time=281.224..771.767 rows=56382 loops=1)
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2735.07..2737.72 rows=265 width=8) (actual time=281.200..302.871 rows=55393 loops=1)
                    ->  Append  (cost=6.83..2733.75 rows=265 width=8) (actual time=0.100..247.291 rows=61448 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.83..990.42 rows=255 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Scan using idx_account_entities_entity_type_id on account_entities ae_i  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (entity_type_id = 2)
                                      Filter: (id = 30710)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on team_members tm  (cost=6.41..979.43 rows=255 width=8) (never executed)
                                      Recheck Cond: (account_entity_id = 30710)
                                      Filter: (NOT deleted)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_team_members_account_entity_id  (cost=0.00..6.34 rows=255 width=0) (never executed)
                                            Index Cond: (account_entity_id = 30710)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.85..844.87 rows=6 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..23.17 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..16.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            ->  Index Scan using account_entities_pkey on account_entities ae_om  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (id = 30710)
                                                  Filter: (entity_type_id = 4)
                                            ->  Index Scan using office_members_pkey on office_members om  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (person_account_entity_id = ae_om.entity_id)
                                      ->  Index Scan using account_entities_pkey on account_entities ae_o  (cost=0.42..6.40 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (id = om.office_account_entity_id)
                                            Filter: (entity_type_id = 3)
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on team_members ctm_1  (cost=5.73..819.04 rows=267 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Recheck Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_o.id)
                                      Filter: (NOT deleted)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_team_members_account_entity_id  (cost=0.00..5.66 rows=267 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_o.id)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.54..895.81 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.056..239.982 rows=61448 loops=1)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.84..66.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.032..10.580 rows=949 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.42..60.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.018..3.128 rows=949 loops=1)
                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.13..23.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..16.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using account_entities_pkey on account_entities ae_om_om  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                              Index Cond: (id = 30710)
                                                              Filter: (entity_type_id = 4)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using office_members_pkey on office_members om2  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                              Index Cond: (person_account_entity_id = ae_om_om.entity_id)
                                                  ->  Index Scan using account_entities_pkey on account_entities ae_o_1  (cost=0.42..6.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (id = om2.office_account_entity_id)
                                                        Filter: (entity_type_id = 3)
                                            ->  Index Scan using idx_office_members_location_id on office_members om_1  (cost=0.29..36.79 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.012..2.872 rows=949 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: (office_account_entity_id = ae_o_1.entity_id)
                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_account_entities_entity_id_entity_type_id_account_id on account_entities ae_om_1  (cost=0.42..6.49 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=949)
                                            Index Cond: ((entity_id = om_1.person_account_entity_id) AND (entity_type_id = 4))
                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on team_members ctm_2  (cost=5.71..826.48 rows=267 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.229 rows=65 loops=949)
                                      Recheck Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_om_1.id)
                                      Filter: (NOT deleted)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_team_members_account_entity_id  (cost=0.00..5.64 rows=267 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=65 loops=949)
                                            Index Cond: (account_entity_id = ae_om_1.id)
              ->  Index Scan using idx_plans_plan_id on plans plan  (cost=0.43..8.39 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=55393)
                    Index Cond: (plan_id = tm.plan_id)
Total runtime: 846.750 ms
```

### Table counts

- team_members: 5,218,086 records
- account_entities: 120,946 records
- office_members: 99,044 records
- plans: 1,841,980 records

#### Account entities

- Individuals (entity type 2): 1 record
- Offices (entity type 3): 21,885 records
- Office members (entity type 4): 99019 records

### Problem

There is a lot of processing here but this apparently used to work when the row counts were smaller. It's not working anymore. Is there something that I can change about the implementation of change within the query that will allow this query to run faster?

A gotcha:
- This information needs to be in real time. No out of date info should be shown to the user.

Comment: When running queries, are you always given an account ID or something like that (always) so we could optimize it for a specific "where clause"?

Comment: Also, do you regularly vacuum/analyze your data? Have you considered or experimented with clustering your data?

Comment: @JoeLove I included a typical use case. / I'm not sure if the production data is being vacuumed or analyzed. This is dev data. / We have considered clustering, yes. Unfortunately it's not something that available to me at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried breaking some of the `SELECT`s up into temp tables which are then used inside the larger query? That can sometimes make a huge difference, although it's certainly very data and schema dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like the following: I believe that your "offices" subquery needs to be busted up into 2 to help the optimizer. You may want to change my union alls to union depending on your need, but the union all will be faster.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.accessible_plans AS (

        -- Plan <-> office
        SELECT tm.plan_id, ae_o.id account_entity_id
        FROM public.team_members tm
        INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_o ON ae_o.id = tm.account_entity_id
            AND ae_o.entity_type_id = 3 -- Office
    INNER JOIN public.office_members om ON om.office_account_entity_id = ae_o.id
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om ON ae_om.entity_id = om.person_account_entity_id
          AND ae_om.entity_type_id = 4 

        WHERE tm.deleted = FALSE

        UNION ALL

        -- Plan <-> office member <-> office
        SELECT tm.plan_id, ae_om2.id office_account_entity_id
        FROM public.team_members tm
        INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om ON ae_om.id = tm.account_entity_id
            AND ae_om.entity_type_id = 4 -- Office member
        INNER JOIN public.office_members om ON om.person_account_entity_id = ae_om.entity_id
        INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_o ON ae_o.entity_id = om.office_account_entity_id
            AND ae_o.entity_type_id = 3 -- Office
        INNER JOIN public.office_members om2 ON om2.office_account_entity_id = ae_o.id
    INNER JOIN public.account_entities ae_om2 ON ae_om2.entity_id = om2.person_account_entity_id
        AND ae_om.entity_type_id = 4 -- Office member
        WHERE tm.deleted = FALSE

    UNION ALL

    -- Plan <-> individual
    SELECT tm.plan_id plan_id, ae.id account_entity_id
    FROM public.account_entities ae
    INNER JOIN public.team_members tm ON tm.account_entity_id = ae.id
    WHERE ae.entity_type_id = 2 -- Individual
        AND tm.deleted = FALSE
);
```

Comment: "CREATE INDEX idx_account_entities_entity_id_entity_type_id_account_id ON account_entities USING btree (entity_id, entity_type_id, account_id);"

did that line work for you? I see no "account_id" in the account_entities table...

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the query, this time I think I've got the joins, etc right. Please give me feedback. I'll continue to see what I can do. Without data, it's hard to know if this sped anything up, but it's a start

Comment: There's a problem with your query. `ae_o.id` in your first select should be `ae_om.id` (offices aren't a part of this list, only their office members.

But no matter, I changed the queries and explain output to reflect your suggestion. I also added schema a row count for the table in the "Typical use" section. 

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Cool. What was the runtime originally? do you remember? It now is sub 1 second (have no idea what it was prior to your performance issues). Is it any faster this way?